# Manga where a goddess gives a character 20xp, then another goddess gives him 1/20 Level Up but he stays jobless

Tags: story-identification, manga

In this manga the main character meets a goddess who she gives him the skill '20xp' and then by accident meets another goddess who gives him '1/20 Level Up'.

When we goes down to the new world he levels up too quickly, thus it keeps him as jobless. Because of this he can learn any job and he can have multiple jobs equipped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[I’ve Became Able to Do Anything with My Growth Cheat, but I Can’t Seem to Get out of Being Jobless](https://myanimelist.net/manga/100407/Seichou_Cheat_de_Nandemo_Dekiru_you_ni_Natta_ga_Mushoku_dake_wa_Yamerarenai_you_desu)* (AKA *Seichou Cheat De Nandemo Dekiru You Ni Natta Ga, Mushoku Dake Wa Yamerarenai You Desu*).

> I, Ichinosuke, failed to get a job for 100 consecutive times.
> Furthermore, my record is still being updated as unemployed.
>
> On my way to a job interview, I was involved in an accident with a
> truck and tragically passed away.
>
> And then, a Goddess bestowed upon me the ability to grow at a speed
> 400 times faster than normal, before sending me to a game-like
> otherworld.
>
> However, knowing that I would not become stronger even if I continued
> growing while jobless, I aimed to get a job, but I found out that it
> was my terrible fate to remain jobless.
>
> As my Growth Cheat and Jobless Cheat existed side-by-side in this
> otherworld, an adventure record, no doubt certified by the
> job-placement agency as a harmful book, begins here.
>
> [image]

Comment: yes that is it thank you so much

Comment: @tdog8881 - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)