# Isekai manga where mc receives two blessings/skills

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I was reading a manga where the MC was reincarnated into another world after receiving two XP related skills/blessings from two goddesses as they had a mix-up and both gave him a skill/blessing when he should only have one, I believe they were something like 20 times growth and 1/20 XP needed, or something along those lines.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Is there anything else you can tell us about this manga? For example, were there any other significant characters? Were there monsters? Was it a full colour manga, or mostly black & white?

Answer (score 3):

As per [Manga where a goddess gives a character 20xp, then another goddess gives him 1/20 Level Up but he stays jobless](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/239447/manga-where-a-goddess-gives-a-character-20xp-then-another-goddess-gives-him-1-2), this is likely *[I've Became Able to Do Anything with My Growth Cheat, but I Can't Seem to Get out of Being Jobless](https://myanimelist.net/manga/100407/Seichou_Cheat_de_Nandemo_Dekiru_you_ni_Natta_ga_Mushoku_dake_wa_Yamerarenai_you_desu)* (AKA *Seichou Cheat De Nandemo Dekiru You Ni Natta Ga, Mushoku Dake Wa Yamerarenai You Desu*).

> I, Ichinosuke, failed to get a job for 100 consecutive times.
> Furthermore, my record is still being updated as unemployed.
>
> On my way to a job interview, I was involved in an accident with a
> truck and tragically passed away.
>
> And then, a Goddess bestowed upon me the ability to grow at a speed
> 400 times faster than normal, before sending me to a game-like
> otherworld.
>
> However, knowing that I would not become stronger even if I continued
> growing while jobless, I aimed to get a job, but I found out that it
> was my terrible fate to remain jobless.
>
> As my Growth Cheat and Jobless Cheat existed side-by-side in this
> otherworld, an adventure record, no doubt certified by the
> job-placement agency as a harmful book, begins here.
>
> [image]

Comment: As per the [tour], you can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. In this case, because it has been asked before, it would be marked as a dupe.

Comment: FWIW, your mention of the 1-to-20 ratio sparked the memory in my head that we'd had this one before.